# Drop box to SharePoint online migration without using third party tools

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-online, dropbox

I want to migrate my client's environment from drop box to SharePoint Online without using third party tools.
Can somebody guide me through the free tools that are available and also which other approaches exist.

I tried using Migration Manager creating drobox account however I am getting below error.
[image]

Comment: Hello @Sagar, you haven't added the error that you are getting.

Comment: @jimas13 added the image.

Comment: taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mm-dropbox-step1-connect is the account that you are utilizing to sign in a Dropbox administrator account?

Comment: seems like its a normal free account used for storage purpose need to sign up for enterprise/business account

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify upon your issue, I opened up a free account in DropBox and I tried to create a connection within the Migration Manager Service, as [it is described in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mm-dropbox-overview).

I also got the error that you had:

[image: DropBox Error]

Based on which I believe that it is required of you to have purchased an Enterprise Dropbox Account and that the free edition of DropBox is not supported, [since you need an account that will be Dropbox administrator account to link with your Microsoft 365 migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mm-dropbox-step1-connect#:%7E:text=Sign%20in%20to%20your%20Dropbox%20administrator%20account%20to%20link%20with%20your%20Microsoft%20365%20migration.).

As an alternative you could sync the DropBox Account Contents onto a File Storage and [set up a Migrations Manager File Share Connection in order to upload all of the contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mm-get-started).
[image]

Comment: Thanks we are trying the same approach actually can you please let us know whether it is possible for BOx Enterprise Admin account to sync data of all users to windows folders with their usernames as root folder as we are trying to setup file migration scripts to transfer them to one drive.

Comment: hi @Sagar, that I do not know since I have mostly used OneDrive, sorry...